# How to simply convert parsed json data from URL to wordpress widget html table

Tags: javascript, html, json, wordpress

Hello I've been searching the internet for about a couple of days now but I only get lost in the deepness of the subject.

What my aim is to get the json data from this URL: https://www.btcturk.com/api/ticker which is something like this;

```
{"high":1565.01,"last":1536.90,"timestamp":1388632896.0,"bid":1540.0,"volume":50.76,"low":1534.00,"ask":1552.00}
```

And I want to print / display / visualize some of the values in html table format, something like this;

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>Alış (Bid): </td>
<td>bid value from json</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Satış (Ask): </td>
<td>ask value from json</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Please notice that the column1 is custom text and column2 is the related jason data.

That's it, I just want to insert the needed code into the HTML (Text ) Widget in Wordpress.

I'm not even sure if I need a plugin to do this, or if I need to download **jquery.js** file to my server can read it externally...

Any help, suggestion, guidance or any kind of reply is greatly appreciated.

I thank you all in advance.

Comment: fisrt thing you cannot do ajax request to cross domain, you can do using jsonp or cors.

Answer (score 0):

if your current page where you want to put the widget is in the same domain, you can use the below snippet as text/html  widget "assuming your page in the same domain https://www.btcturck.com"

```
 <div class="result"></div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function() {
    jQuery.ajax( {
       url: "https://www.btcturk.com/api/ticker",
    }). done(
    function( data ) {
       var data = JSON.parse(data);
       html = '<table><tr><td>BID</td><td>'+data.bid+'</td></table>';
       $('.result').html(html);
    });
 };
 </script>
```

I have used window onload because I don't know when your jquery library will be loaded.